# Objective C framework for social network and web services integration

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, social-networking

In my app I want to provide a strong integration with social network and web services (**facebook, flickr, youtube, picasa, dropbox**… and more!).
To implement such integration, I'm currently using several libraries like Facebook iOS SDK, objectiveFlickr and so on.
The problem is that I have several dependencies and I created my own wrappers in order to use the same interfaces in my classes, and I fear that the things are going to become more complex and hard to manage as soon I integrate new services.
So, my question is: **is there a framework with an high level of abstraction that make easy (or less painful) these integrations?**

ps: **ShareKit** it's far away from what I need! :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need ShareKit: http://getsharekit.com/

Comment: Get the Sharekit 2.0 version from github: https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit. It's still being developed, where as the orginal version is not under developement any more.

Comment: I explicitly wrote that sharekit is not what I need!

Comment: So why not take ShareKit as a starting point? Add what you see is missing and release it back to the community!

Comment: The project is cool, but I need more than a GUI for share stuff, I want a flexible framework to exchange data from/to my app and the service (in background threads)

Comment: Hmm didn't see you PS when I wrote my answer. I agree with daveoncode:  use the code that sharekit uses to communicate with these services and neglect the gui.

Answer (score 1):

@daveoncode you might try Socialize: http://www.GetSocialize.com (full feature list at http://go.GetSocialize.com/features).  Right now Socialize supports Facebook, with Twitter coming this month and Google+ next, but it the SDKs are open source so you can always offload to Socialize what it can do and then handle the rest yourself.  Let me know if that's helpful.

DROdio